# How to compile c# csproj into exe in Visual Studio 2015 - error CS0579

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

Pretty new to C# and Visual Studio. I started with a .exe that needed modification, decompiled it in .NET Reflector, then opened the Assembly in Visual Studio 2015. I have made my change and clicked "Build" and now I get two errors with code "CS0579... Description: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute" (the second is the same but without 'global::')

I don't have a reputation of 10 yet, so I cannot post my screenshot.

Need to get past this. any Help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the second TargetFrameworkAttribute?

Comment: Thanks. Here is the line I think may be suspect, in 'AssemblyInfo.cs' :  [assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4 Client Profile")]                     How much of it do I need to cut out, and is this the correct spot?

Comment: The first error happens if I do Build+Intellisense. If I do Build Only, There is also an error here: Error CS0579 Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute JRUniFlowProLawTransfer C:\Users\<me.domain>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Comment: Are there 2 AssemblyInfo files? That might be the cause. You should delete the entire line

Comment: Booya! Here is the Output after deleting the first [assembly:...  line:            1>------ Build started: Project: JRUniFlowProLawTransfer, Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>  JRUniFlowProLawTransfer -> I:\Customers\<customername>\Source Code\bin\Release\JRUniFlowProLawTransfer.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept my answer so we both win

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the swift reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error CS0579 Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997928/errorcs0579duplicate-globalsystem-runtime-versioning-targetframeworkattribu)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should delete this entire line from AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Cl‌​ient", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4 Client Profile")]
```

Comment: I found on the internet a lot of solutions, but none worked, this one did. A lot of time lost for this error, a lot of answers with the solution proposed by @espumita but those ones didn't worked, more than that raised another errors. This worked like a charm, thank (after 7 years :)) )

Answer (score 3):

I had today the error CS0579 related to some AssemblyInfo and TargetFrameworkAttribute duplicated values. Using sdk 3.1.301 and targetting netcoreapp3.1 and with some other projects targeting netstandard2.1

Using this:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

And deleting /bin & /obj fixed my build.

Answer (score 0):

global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute

```cs
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Cl‌​ient", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4 Client Profile")]
```

You can delete line directly from the project. To Delete click and navigate on an error then remove this line, after that build the program and run again.